# How to fix ETIMEDOUT error after npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm

This is the error I receive:

[image: ETIMEDOUT error after npm install]

I get similar errors in other projects as well after npm install.

Comment: Are you using Windows ?

Comment: ubuntu wsl. I tried to run this project on windows aswell, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the server you are trying to access is up. The address is a little sketchy. Ping should do the trick:

```sh
$ ping http://bbdr.dcc.com.de:5005
```

If pinging is successful, make sure that your firewall is not blocking traffic.

Comment: not successful. ping http://bbdr.dcc.com.de:5005: Name or service not known

Comment: Then that means that the server is down. Is that server yours?

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, check if `$ ping http://bbdr.dcc.com.de:5005` works.
And if you are not behind any proxy, then try below commands -

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Comment: that's the problem that the domain is not working, it could simply go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie, but it goes to not working domain. For other people who work in this project npm install works fine.

Comment: And i already tried things with rm proxy, set registry etc.

Comment: Not sure, it can be an issue with WSL network as well.

Comment: on windows problem remains